# Trigger a spellcheck in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, spell-checking

I am making an editor without relying on contenteditable, in order to get a clean, controlled output. So I'm catching all keyboard and mouse events, building a model and creating a DOM view from that model.

Since I need spellcheck, I activated contenteditable in divs in my view. The user doesn't interact with it, because I'm catching all events.

The problem I have is that spellchecking only seems to be activated on user input on the contenteditable div, which in my case happens only when I right-click somewhere on the text (because I'm not catching that). I've found a question that just says we shouldn't expect spellchecking to be active at the beginning - but in my case even when the user types, spellchecking doesn't happens (because he doesn't type in the contenteditable, I'm building it).

[HTML spellcheck in contenteditable div not working after span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123674/html-spellcheck-in-contenteditable-div-not-working-after-span)

So is there a way I can trigger an event that would make the browser think the user is interacting with the contenteditable?

Update: that's only for Chrome, in Firefox the spellchecker works even without events directly caused by the user.

Answer (score 0):

If the focus is still on the contenteditable then setting `spellcheck` attribute of the contenteditable div to `false` and then back to `true` seems to trigger spellcheck again on Chrome.