# Force chrome to spellcheck a contenteditable div where content was manually set

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, contenteditable

Just a div with contenteditable and then manually setting innerHTML to a text with typos

```js
editor.innerHTML="helo helo<br>hrlo<br>"
```

```html
<div contenteditable=true id=editor style="border:solid;border-width:1px"></div>
```

How can I tell chrome to spellcheck this text ?

I know that officially you need a user interaction and that forceSpellCheck() is not supported yet by Chrome. Is there another hack/workaround ??

Thx!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML spellcheck in contenteditable div not working after span](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123674/html-spellcheck-in-contenteditable-div-not-working-after-span)

Comment: maybe similar but this is a much simpler case, no spans involved

Comment: The question is superficially different, but the answer is exactly the same.